# When I change the route a song stops playing. How to make dynamic audio?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an issue with dynamic audio player.

So, I have a page with music and by clicking on 'play' at any song it runs a function

```
playSong (song) {
    var payload = {
        name: song,
        audio: new Audio(require(`@/assets/audio/music/${this.genre}/${song}.mp3`))
    };
    this.$store.commit('playSong', payload);
}
```

As you can see it commits a mutation in store:

```
mutations: {
    playSong (state, payload) {
        state.playingSong.name = payload.name;
        state.playingSong.audio = payload.audio;
    },
}
```

Then I want to play this song without stopping at every single page of my app. **My App.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view/>
        <musicPlayer v-if="playingSong.audio"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

// Components
import musicPlayer from '@/components/musicPlayer.vue'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        musicPlayer
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            playingSong: 'getPlayingSong',
        })
    },
}
</script>
```

Here you can see that I import component, which I will show later and I get state of playingSong:

```
state: {
    playingSong: {
        audio: null,
        name: null,
    },
}
```

After it, if there is a playing song I run my component 'musicPlayer.vue'

```
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

export default {
    mounted () {
        this.playingSong.audio.play();
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            playingSong: 'getPlayingSong',
        })
    },
}
</script>
```

So if when I click on a song it plays, but if I change path, for example from 'localhost:8080/Music' to 'localhost:8080/Home' the song stops playing

Comment: Have you tried using something like [vue-portal](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) in order to render your `musicPlayer` outside the Vue controlled DOM? If you're using Nuxt btw, this should be very easy to implement without using any plugin, just [layouts](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#layouts).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind, but I've found another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use

```
<router-link to="/Page"></router-link>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/Page"></a>
```

And that's all the problem :)

[Learn more about router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/api/)